# SAP UI5 Popover not showing the content properly if the content is PAGE

Tags: javascript, jquery, popover, sapui5

I am trying to put **XML view** which contains **page** as the content, and placing that inside the **popover**, xmlviewXML view I am using is like this,

```
<mvc:View controllerName="controllerPath"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" height="100%" width="100%">
    <Page height="100%"
          width="100%">
    <content>
       //some content...
    </content>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

And I am creating popover like this inside the fragment,

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <Popover
        title="{Name}"
        class="sapUiContentPadding"
        placement="Bottom">
       //placing above view here...
    </Popover>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

But if I do that it will not show the page inside the popover because of some height issue. And I want to set the height of the popover based on the view height(popover content height).i tried by using popover **contentHeight="auto"**
but this will not work.So how to show the popover based on its content?

Comment: Do not use a view: directly put the page inside your Popover, and you'll end up with what you want :) (view Require the parent control to have explicit height when popover ask its size to its child : the 2 of them can not work together as you expect)

Comment: Actually, this popover is a generic container in that I have to place whatever the view I get dynamically..so is there any solution for this?

Comment: setting explicit height and width to the view might work ? (not 100%, a size in px)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no height and width property for the sap.m.Page control. However, the sap.ui.core.View does have height and width property. So, assign width and height to View and not page.

Code:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="controllerPath"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" height="50rem"
          width="50rem">
    <Page >
    <content>
       //some content...
    </content>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Also, let the default width and height for Popover. Let me know if this works for your requirement.

Update: I gave 100% height and 100% width to the view embedded also set 100% for contentHeight and contentWidth of Popover. I got the entire page. Screenshot is attached.

[image]

Comment: Yes, even I gave height and width to view then also the same problem. and height and width should not be static like in PX or REM, if I give height and width of view in percentage then also the same problem.

Comment: @ManjunathM Updated answer. Let me know if this works

Comment: Thanks, but I want that content height based on the content of the page i.e. that popover should show only till the text ends and the space below that is of no use...so how to achieve that?